# How do you add the values from input fields and update another field with the result in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preamble: I'm more of a PHP/MySQL guy, just starting to dabble in javascript/jQuery, so please excuse this dumb newbie question. Couldn't figure it out from the Docs.

I have a form without a submit button. The goal is to allow the user to input values into several form fields and use jQuery to total them up on the bottom in a div. The form kinda looks like this but prettier:

```
<form>
Enter Value: <input class="addme" type="text" name="field1" size="1">
Enter Value: <input class="addme" type="text" name="field2" size="1">
Enter Value: <input class="addme" type="text" name="field3" size="1">
etc.....
<div>Result:<span id="result"></span></div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to add these up? And if so, can it be done anytime one of the input fields changes?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Brian posted a cool collaborative sandbox so I edited the code to look more like what I have and it's here:
http://jsbin.com/orequ/
to edit go here:
http://jsbin.com/orequ/edit

Comment: Are they whole numbers or can they be anything?

Comment: The user is supposed to input integers...if he doesn't then I'd like it to just be ignored.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. This is the best and fastest response I ever got on SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking this right after the `</form>` tag should do it:

```
<script>
  function displayTotal() {
    var sum = 0

    var values = $('.addme').each(function(){
      sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
    });

    $('#result').text(sum);
  }
  $('.addme').keyup(displayTotal);
</script>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/iboqo (Editable via http://jsbin.com/iboqo/edit)

Comment: Thanks...your demo works perfectly with the code I gave you but when I add in my actual code it doesn't work. It just says NaN (which Alex' reply did too if I jiggered with it)...maybe because the real form is in a table? Or because I don't really have a div around the span? I'm going to play with it some more in that sandbox (very cool btw).

Comment: It's probably because some of your fields are empty. It adds to NaN because parseInt(x) === NaN if x is an empty string or a string that contains non-integer characters. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/parseInt). I've edited my answer to correct for empty or non-numeric values

Comment: OK I'll check yours and Russ Cam's in a second. Here's my updated example just in case you miss my updated question:
http://jsbin.com/orequ/

Comment: Thanks for the help Brian! And the sandbox, that is awesome!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, there's a missing semicolon after `var sum = 0`. JavaScript doesn't require semicolons, but it's always a good idea to use them in order to reduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".addme").bind("change",function(){
    var _sum = 0;

    $(".addme").each(function(i){
        _sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $("#result").val(_sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Any non numeric or blank values will be disregarded in the calculation (they'll be given a value of zero and hence not affect the sum).

```
function sumValues() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input.addme").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var amount = parseInt($this.val(), 10);
        sum += amount === "" || isNaN(amount)? 0 : amount;
    });

    $("#result").text(sum);
}

$(function() {

  sumValues();

  $("input.addme").keyup(function(){
    sumValues();
  });

});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/uhaxe)**

Comment: I'm sure yours works too, though since Brian's did also I didn't check. Voted you up. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){
    var context = $("form"), elements = $("input.addme", context);
    function getSum(elements) {
        var sum = 0;
        $(elements, context).each( function() {
            var v = parseInt(this.value);
            v === parseInt(v,10) ? sum += v : sum = sum;
        })
        return sum;
    }
    $(elements).bind("keyup", function() {
        $("#result").text( getSum(elements) );
    });
})();
```

isolated scope and context, included dealing with non-integer values, function getSum should rather return a value than do something itself.